# How to get complete history from different tty or pts

Tags: ubuntu, git-bash, tty

**Background:**
Local machine is Win10 64bit with `GitBash`
Remote server running Ubuntu 16.04 64bit
Sometimes after `ssh` to the remote server, if `GitBash` left more than several minutes, the terminal with frozen. No command could be typed in anymore, so I have to close the `GitBash` window. It would prompt like

> Processes are running in session:
>   |  PID   TTY  COMMAND
>   | *number* pty3  /usr/bin/bash
>   | *number* pty3  /usr/bin/ssh
>   Close anyway?

So after it is closed, next time login in, the history will not show as expected.
After some search, `who -la` command was tried and shows

```
root@linux:#who -la
           system boot  2018-**-** 17:32
LOGIN      tty1         2018-**-** 09:59              7370 id=tty1
           run-level 5  2018-**-** 09:32
root     - pts/8        2018-**-** 11:10              9330 (222.**.**.223)
root     - pts/9        2018-**-** 11:18             10485 (222.**.**.223)
root     - pts/10       2018-**-** 11:11   .         19316 (222.**.**.223)
           pts/11       2018-**-** 17:26             18164 id=s/11  term=0 exit=0
           pts/8        2018-**-** 17:00                 0 id=/8    term=0 exit=0
           pts/11       2018-**-** 14:39                 0 id=/11   term=0 exit=0
           pts/9        2018-**-** 14:01                 0 id=/9    term=0 exit=0
           pts/12       2018-**-** 13:56              6899 id=s/12  term=0 exit=0
LOGIN      tty2         2018-**-** 09:58              7324 id=tty2
LOGIN      tty6         2018-**-** 10:09              9148 id=tty6
```

Tried to kill other pts with `kill PID` like **9330** and **10485**, after that 
some part of the `who -la` result changed like.

```
       pts/8        2018-**-** 11:11              9330 id=ts/8  term=0 exit=0
       pts/9        2018-**-** 11:11             10485 id=ts/9  term=0 exit=0
```

But if `kill PID` of the `tty`s

```
LOGIN      tty2         2018-**-** 11:12             19617 id=tty2
LOGIN      tty6         2018-**-** 11:12             19689 id=tty6
```

they only change the `PID`, so **are they not been really killed?**
Tried to change `tty` with `chvt n` command to get history type in former `tty`.
But no matter what `n` is in `chvt n` command, `tty` command will give the same result like `/dev/pts/8`
So should the pts be switched? Is that possible? Then how?
If not, what is the right path to get the former history?

ps: why there are 3 `LOGIN`s in `who -la` result?

Comment: Why not use WSL? (an actual bash)

Comment: @VonC WSL is too young, I think, would try it later. And in this question, I think Git Bash is not the cause of it probably.

Comment: OK. I mentioned it because WSL is not so young anymore, quite mature and complete actually.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and also your help on my other problems. Thinking install WSL would be a bother before since git bash is provided by git already and it works fine. After some search find it's quite simple and easy. Installed and using it now.

Comment: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1023 can be related

Comment: Not that related actually, it's about default confirm closing after prompt. But what to do after it's closed is more concerned by me.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a programming question to me.